# sql - does join create a new table?

Tags: sql

when I use join in mysql (or sql) does it create a new table?
Or does it create a virtual table like the view command?

Comment: A JOIN does not create a new table, or even a virtual table. Rather it simply describes a relational algebra operation. The SQL implementation only needs to use this operation to generate a compatible result set.

Comment: A join creates a result set. Nothing is stored.

Comment: Join is a part of SQL statement. It cannot create something itself - even in theory.

Comment: Also niether does *view* create any form of table, it defines query logic the the optimizer uses to combine with the invoking query, either in whole or in part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, it doesn't create the new table within the database but it only shows the output of the table. Yeah, it is just a kind of output
For example I have two tables

[image: Table_1]

[image: Table_2]

my join query:

```
--Alias inner join
select t1.Table2_id, t1.[Name], t1.Class,
t1.Age, t2.Fee, t2.No_of_courses from Table_1 as t1
inner join Table_2 as t2  on  
t1.Table2_id=t2.id
```

[image: Output]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnzLc.png)

So it's just the temporary to show us the result of the join.

Answer (score 1):

Each query result is a table. It consists of columns and rows and can be treated like any other table in SQL. E.g.:

```
select *
from departments
join
(
  select department_id, count(*) as number_of_employees
  from employees
  group by department_id
) department_info using (department_id);
```

Here we create a table we call department_info in our query and join this table to the existing departments table. This creates another table now consisting of departments plus the number of employees in it. This is the query result we show.

It is a query (`select ...`) which creates a table. The join is just a part of it.

These tables, however, are only temporary. While departments and employees in above example are stored tables, department_info and the final query result are not. They don't get stored. If you want to store a query's result table, use `CREATE TABLE AS`. E.g.:

```
create table department_employees as
select *
from departments
join
(
  select department_id, count(*) as number_of_employees
  from employees
  group by department_id
) department_info using (department_id);
```

Comment: In `select * from x x1 join x x2 on x1.i = x2.i join x x3 on x2.i = x3.i`, how many “tables” are created? Consider x is a table with a single i column (uniqueness not guaranteed).

Comment: This is one query (one select), so this produces one table, the query result.